# ASP.NET: Fileupload filename gone after preview image

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I'm doing an employee registration were there is an image that the user can preview the picture they choose. So my problem is, when I tried to preview the selected image, the filename in the fileupload is gone..

[image]

the "save-14-copy.png" is the filename of the picture.

So next step is to preview the image..

[image]

So as you can see the "save-14-copy.png" is already gone after hitting the button preview.

How can I retain the filename so I will not get an error when saving it.?

Code for design:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1"  Text="PREVIEW"  CssClass="button-green" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ImagePreview(Imagepath) {
    if (Imagepath.files && Imagepath.files[0]) {
        var Filerdr = new FileReader();
        Filerdr.onload = function (e) {
            document.getElementById("<%= hfImage.ClientID %>").value = e.target.result; 
        }
        Filerdr.readAsDataURL(Imagepath.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  EmpImage.ImageUrl = hfImage.Value;
}
```

Comment: You preview button looks like it would cause a postback and submits the file to the server, after postback you have a fresh reloaded page so there is no file selected any more.  I can't see how the JS you have posted would even run unless you have other code that wires it to the click event of the button.

Comment: @BenRobinson.. I see.. I tested it its refresh the page but the text in my textbox is still there..How can I fix this one?>

Comment: the textbox uses viewstate to store and load the value. if it's about the filename, use a literal or a hidden field to store the filename in viewstate

Comment: @fubo.. i tried that...but it gives me a base64 string instead the filename or full path

Answer (score 1):

i think you should save the file at preview-click and handle the filename there

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  hfImagename.Value = fuFile.PostedFile.FileName;
  fuFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(@"C:\foo\"  +fuFile.PostedFile.FileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *Preview* button is actually causing a post back to the server. The way you have it setup now, the Preview button would be more appropriately called *Upload*.

You are using the `FileReader` object in order to read the file from the user's local file system and showing it in the image before upload. All of that should take place only in the client. Once the user is happy with the selected picture, he can upload the picture to the server.

Here is a very simple sample that should get you started.

### .aspx file

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Image ID="preview" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/NotSelectedYet.jpg" />
        <br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="pictureOfMe" runat="server" /> 
        <input type="button" value="Preview" onclick="Preview();" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Upload" runat="server" Text="Upload file to server" OnClick="Upload_Clicked" />
    </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Preview() {
            var fileInput = document.getElementById('<%= pictureOfMe.ClientID  %>');
            var filePreview = document.getElementById('<%= preview.ClientID %>');
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            var imageType = /image.*/;

            if (file.type.match(imageType)) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    filePreview.src = reader.result;
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
            else {
                alert('Not an image file!');
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Here we have an image that is showing a default picture when first loaded. Then we have a file upload control that lets the user select a picture to upload. And we have an html input button that the user clicks on to preview the selected picture. When this button is clicked, it runs javascript code that uses the `FileReader` to load the file an show it in the image. Note that the preview button will not cause a post back to the server.

And we also have a server button that will post the page (including the selected picture) to the server with a server event handler declared.

### .aspx.cs file

```
public partial class TestImagePreviewAndUpload : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Upload_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(pictureOfMe.PostedFile.FileName != string.Empty) {
            byte[] uploadedBytes = pictureOfMe.FileBytes;
            //save uploaded picture here
        }
    }
}
```

Here, in the `Upload_Clicked` method we check if a file was uploaded and gets the file content as a `byte[]`. Actuelly storing the file is left as an exercise...

Note: Sample javascript (with some modifications) from [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api)